# Unable to use bsh.shared to share an array between thread groups in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

I couldn't get to use bsh.shared namespace to share an array between thread groups, please guide me on this

Following is the structure of my jmx file:

1. ThreadGroup1

   - Sampler1

     - Beanshell-PostProcessor1
2. ThreadGroup2

   - Sampler2

     - Beanshell-PreProcessor2

Inside BeanshellPostProcessor1,

```
if (bsh.shared.names == void){
   bsh.shared.names = new java.util.ArrayList();
}
String[] arr = vars.get("fruits").split(',');
for(int i =0;i < arr.length; i++){
    if (arr[i].contains("APPLE")){
        bsh.shared.names.add[arr[i]]
    }

}
```

When I try to access bsh.shared.names inside Beanshell-PreProcessor2, it doesn't return the value.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems with your code, to wit:

1. You need to replace `split(',')` with `split(",")` because [String.split()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) function takes String as the parameter and you're providing a char
2. You need to replace `bsh.shared.names.add[arr[i]]` with `bsh.shared.names.add(arr[i]);` as this is the correct way of calling [ArrayList.add()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add-E-) function

Full code just in case:

```
if (bsh.shared.names == void){
  bsh.shared.names = new java.util.ArrayList();
}
String[] arr = vars.get("fruits").split(",");
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if (arr[i].contains("APPLE")) {
      bsh.shared.names.add(arr[i]);
  }
}
```

Also be aware that [starting from JMeter 3.1 it is recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) because [Groovy performance is much higher](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/).

There is no `bsh.shared` namespace in Groovy however you should be able to use `props` shorthand instead, it will do the same trick for you.